# Rails Routing INSIDE CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, routes, assets

Is there any way I can route assets inside of my css to where the  rest of the views are pulling them? I mean, inside the CSS can I call url_for or css_for or something like that in order to have the images go through the assets router?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You don't want requests that can be handled by the web server to go through Rails. Only requests requiring application logic should be put through routing.

Could you clarify why you'd like to do this? There may be a better answer.

Comment: Because the CSS links to assets, and the location for those assets is set in the production.rb. I would like to set that once, and have all assets look to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a controller action to render your CSS (with an erb template) and set the content type to `text/css`.

Take a look at this blog post from Josh Susser on [dynamically generated stylesheets](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/3/23/dirt-simple-rcss-templates). It is from 2006 but the technique described is still applicable.

Comment: That is really helpful! Actually, we considered using it because as an asset, you can vary which server gets called for cache using %d wildcards. However, if we have to invoke rails to generate CSS, it might be faster to just to hardcode one Cache server for CSS.